# Do we know the names of all Gorosei members?

Tags: one-piece

In the One Piece world, the Gorosei are some kind of top leaders of the World Government. They are usually in the Marine HQ. Do we know their names?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [One Piece wiki page on Gorosei](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gorosei), it seems that the names haven't been revealed yet.

> The Gorosei (literally meaning "Five Elder Stars") are the heads of the World Government, and as such, they essentially rule the entire world. They are the five men who rule above the Marines, Cipher Pol, and the ones who made a pact with the Shichibukai. **So far, none of their names have been revealed.**

But there is some other additional information given about their appearances and history and that can be read from the [wiki page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gorosei) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Now we finally know their name:

> [image]

> Saint Jaygarcia Saturn
>  Saint Marcus Mars
>  Saint Topman Warcury
>  Saint Ethanbaron V. Nusjuro
>  Saint Shepherd Ju Peter

Comment: I guess adding a chapter number may help to give context for the spoiler?

Answer (score 0):

Their names and ranks have been revealed in One Piece [chapter 1086](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_1086), "The Five Elders". They hold the title of 武神 (Bushin), which has been translated as either "Warrior God" or "Godhead".

From left to right in your image:

- Saint Shepherd Ju Peter ( シェパード・十(ジュウ)・ピーター聖 ), Warrior God of Agriculture (農務武神);
- Saint Ethanbaron V. Nusjuro (イーザンバロン・V(ブイ)・ナス寿郎聖), Warrior God of Finance (財務武神);
- Saint Topman Warcury (トップマン・ウォーキュリー聖), Warrior God of Justice (法務武神);
- Saint Marcus Mars ( マーカス・マーズ聖 ), Warrior God of Environment (環境武神);
- Saint Jaygarcia Saturn ( ジェイガルシア・サターン聖 ), Warrior God of Science and Defense (科学防衛武神).

You can refer to https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Five_Elders for more information.

For the record, they are never at Marine HQ (at least not that I recall): for instance, in your image they're in Pangaea Castle, Mary Geoise.